# How to change the phpdoc tags color in brackets

Tags: phpdoc, adobe-brackets

Is it possible to change the comment block tags color "phpdoc" like `@package, @link, @author` etc in brackets?

[Photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLm0e.png)

Comment: Looks like you are using Sublime. Sublime > Preferences > Color Scheme should present you with a theme file to modify. You want to modify the 'Annotations'.

Comment: @Rome_Leader Thanks for your answer, I used to use Sublime text that's why I'm looking for this feature in Brackets.